# Distinguish two finger rotation and simple tap

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

In my *fragment* I have a *TextView* and underneath there are two buttons. 
I need to implement a **OnTouchListener** to do two things:

1. When I rotate my two fingers, the *TeXtView* will rotate
2. When I tap the *TeXtView*, the buttons underneath are called

Right now it doesnt work but I cant find better solution.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:context="com.fjord.yalc.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/player_fragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.fjord.yalc.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/normal_start"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:textSize="300sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
Btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.setText(String.valueOf(++life));
            }
        });

        mRotationDetector = new RotationGestureDetector(this);



        TV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

                switch (maskedAction) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: {
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                        mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a week I found the answer. I needed to dispatch my *MotionEvent* to parent of my buttons using *dispatchTouchEvent*. ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is for checking if user uses two fingers.
Now rotation goes to *mRotationDetector* and taps goes to *onClickListener*s of the buttons underneath the *TextView* player.

JAVA:

```
player.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                MotionEvent me = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
                switch (event.getActionMasked()){
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                        flag=true;
                        break;
                    case(MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN):
                        flag=false;
                        break;
                }

                buttons.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Give yourself a pat on the back for the percistence